# Apache thread MEMORY Usage

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, memory-usage

I am facing an issue over the site i am working on, even in very low load of around 10-20 page views per second, the CPU usage maxes out, with all cores running at 100% plus the apache thread memory size keeps on increasing.

We have a server having 4 cores and 34GB as RAM, after some time the memory max out and when i look at apache thread using top command, i can see most of the apache threads in sleep mode but each occupying around 500-600 MB memory.

Its like apache thread is not releasing memory even going into sleep.

Comment: what is your question? how do you evaluate memory usage?

Comment: By memory here i mean RAM usage - physical memory, I check it with using commands like top and htop, which shows me details and i can see the RES part for apache thread which started from 98M going upto 800M for threads and staying there even the thread is in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

CPU load depends on application logic, regarding RAM - RES part is inaccurate and won't show you the real usage of physical memory. I recommend you to test memory with https://raw.github.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py and check application logic.

Comment: When i ran his script it gave me the same picture :see report below  1.9 MiB + 184.5 KiB =   2.1 MiB       sendmail-mta
  1.9 MiB + 595.5 KiB =   2.4 MiB       sshd (2)
  1.8 MiB +   1.4 MiB =   3.3 MiB       nginx (3)
 10.1 MiB +  58.0 KiB =  10.2 MiB       screen
 20.6 MiB +   1.0 MiB =  21.6 MiB       bash (7)
112.2 MiB + 220.5 KiB = 112.5 MiB       newrelic-daemon (2)
 20.9 GiB +  98.9 MiB =  21.0 GiB       apache2 (154)
---------------------------------
                         21.2 GiB
=================================
My apache threads occupying 20GB+ memory..

Comment: then you should check your configuration and logic of your application. Still, I don't see the question.

Comment: May be this can help you understand what i am asking here, i have a clustered production environment, where as i have a development environment which is a single server environment, this memory issue is not occurring on my development environment. I have same code base plus the same database on dev environment.